# Why clang doesn't produce warning about shadowing?

Tags: c++, g++, warnings, clang++

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
  A(int x) {
    y_ = x;
  }
  void x() {
  }
  int y_;
};
int main() {
}
```

If I compile it with latest clang with use of -Weverything it won't produce any warning. But if I compile it with g++ with -Wall -Wshadow it will produce

```
x.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A(int)’:
x.cpp:2:12: warning: declaration of ‘x’ shadows a member of 'this' [-Wshadow]
   A(int x) {
        ^
```

Why these two produce different warnings? Who is right? Is it bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't they produce different warnings?  Neither is "right".  The Standard doesn't mandate a warning for something like this, so it's entirely up to the compiler writers to decide what they think their users might find a warning useful.

Note that any confusion about which `x` was being used would likely result in either an attempt to "call" a variable (which can make sense for a functor) or to assign to or read from a function... many (but not all) such accidental users would be outright compiler errors anyway.  For many people (including me) naming conventions ala `member_variable_` remove potential for the parameter to clash with a member variable.

I've never wanted such a warning, and knowing GCC offers one and being a frequent and happy GCC user wouldn't lead me to turn it on, so it's arguable whether there's value in such a warning.  Hard to know how often it might result in a bug being avoided, versus how often it might remove attention from more important warnings or actual coding, resulting in more bugs!